# float placement options appearing in pdf document

Tags: floats, optional-arguments

I have a latex document that contains lots of floats, and so I want to place them all at the end of the pdf.

I have done this using:

```
\usepackage[nomarkers, nolists]{endfloat}
```

Above all of my images though, I have the `[!]` from my

```
\begin{figure*}[!]
```

I'm obviously doing something stupid. Could anyone tell me what it is please?

---

Here is a working example of my problem. Where the plots should be, you can see `[htbp]`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib]{mnras}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Advanced maths commands
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Extra maths symbols


\title[title}

\author[K. T. Smith et al.]{
Keith T. Smith,$^{1}$\thanks{E-mail: mn@ras.org.uk (KTS)}
A. N. Other,$^{2}$
Third Author$^{2,3}$
and Fourth Author$^{3}$
\\
$^{1}$Royal Astronomical Society, Burlington House, Piccadilly, London W1J 0BQ, UK\\
$^{2}$Department, Institution, Street Address, City Postal Code, Country\\
$^{3}$Another Department, Different Institution, Street Address, City Postal Code, Country
}


\date{Accepted XXX. Received YYY; in original form ZZZ}

\pubyear{2015}

\begin{document}
\label{firstpage}
\pagerange{\pageref{firstpage}--\pageref{lastpage}}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is a simple template for authors to write new MNRAS papers.
The abstract should briefly describe the aims, methods, and main results of the paper.
It should be a single paragraph not more than 250 words (200 words for Letters).
No references should appear in the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
keyword1 -- keyword2 -- keyword3
\end{keywords}

\section{Introduction}
Introduction
\section{Observations}
Observations.
\section{Data Analysis}
\label{dataanalysis}
Data analysis
\section{Results}
results
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=150mm]{plot.png}
\caption{Plot caption}
\label{}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=150mm]{plot2.png}
\caption{caption2}
\label{}
\end{center}
\end{figure*}

\bsp    % typesetting comment
\label{lastpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What mean `[!]`? Try omit it.

Comment: Well, I mean whatever float placement options I have ([!htb] for example) - they appear in the text.

Comment: I suggest to omit `!`. Just use `[htbp]` or nothing. If this not help, than you need to read `endfloat` documentation. I'm not familiar with this package.

Comment: Yeah it still happens without the ! I will read more about endfloat. Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide minimal working example which shows your problem. With it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given in the manual of the document class:

> The LaTeX float placement commands `[htbp]` are intentionally disabled. Layout of figures and tables will be adjusted by
>   the publisher during the production process, so authors should not
>   concern themselves with placement to avoid disappointment and
>   wasted effort.

As the floating environment are redefined to not have an optional argument, `[..]` is interpreted as normal text, and printed in the document.